# Why does keyDown event listener seem to randomly trigger the wrong function?

Tags: javascript, function, debugging, event-listener, keydown

I have the following event listener that is supposed to trigger certain functions when specific keys are pressed down:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (pressed) {
if ('1234567890-*x/+().'.includes(pressed.key)) {
    let value = pressed.key;
    getInput(value);
}

// pressing c clears display
else if (pressed.keyCode === 67) {
    resetDisplay();
}

// pressing delete key deletes last
else if (pressed.keyCode === 8) {
    delLast();
}

// pressing return/enter key sets equals
else if (pressed.keyCode === 13 || pressed.key === '=') {
    updateHistory();
} else return

})
```

The above code seems to work ~75% of the time as expected. However, randomly, pressing specifically the Enter key will call the function that is supposed to be called by pressing down the 'c' key. I cannot figure out why this might be happening. Adding a console.log(pressed.keyCode) statement to the conditional block for the enter key prints 13 to the console whenever Enter key is pressed, even when the wrong function (resetDisplay) function is triggered.

The resetDisplay function is below:

```
function resetDisplay() {
if (string.length == 0) {
    string = '0';
}
document.getElementById('history').innerHTML = 'ans = ' + 
ans;
string = '0';
updateDisplay();
string = '';

}
```

The function being called inside of updateHistory, updateDisplay, follows:

```
function updateDisplay() {
document.getElementById("current").innerHTML = string;
}
```

** I am editing to note that I changed the 'if' statements in the function to 'if/else' statements and ma still encountering the issue. Adding

```
    console.log(pressed.key);
console.log(pressed.keyCode);
```

Shows that the Enter key is logged even when the wrong function is called.

Here is an attempt to generate a minimum reproducible example using the functions above. Please note again that I can't get this to occur consistently, it seems to happen about 25% of the time. The bug I'm encountering is that randomly on pressing enter, the 'history' div is set to the 'ans = ' format that is supposed to result from pressing the c key.

```js
let string = '';
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(pressed) {
  console.log(pressed.key);
  console.log(pressed.keyCode);

  if ('1234567890-*x/+().'.includes(pressed.key)) {
    let value = pressed.key;
    string = value;
    updateDisplay();
  }
  // pressing c clears display
  else if (pressed.keyCode === 67) {
    resetDisplay();
  }

  // pressing return/enter key sets equals
  else if (pressed.keyCode === 13 || pressed.key === '=') {
    updateDisplay();
    document.getElementById("history").innerHTML = string + ' = ';
  } else return;

})

function resetDisplay() {
  if (string.length == 0) {
    string = '0';
  }

  document.getElementById('history').innerHTML = 'ans = ' +
    string;
  string = '0';
  updateDisplay();
  string = '';
}

function updateDisplay() {
  document.getElementById("current").innerHTML = string;
}
```

```html
<div id="screen">
  <p id='history'>0</p>
  <p id='current'>0</p>
</div>
```

Comment: try with `} else if {` instead of just `if` ? I'm curious. Because obviously one key can't trigger all four `if`s

Comment: @JeremyThille I've changed the ifs to else ifs and have tried executing the code a bunch of times without the bug described above appearing. Maybe that fixed it? It's frustrating because it seems to happen randomly and I can't replicate it on purpose, so I don't know if it's not showing up due to luck of the draw or because I haven't tested it enough.

Comment: Try putting `console.log(pressed.key, pressed.keyCode)`; at the top of the function.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: @Barmar I've attempted to add a MRE to the above. Please note that I can't get the bug to occur consistently, so it's hard to derive a reproducible example. The snippet I added above should contain all the essential elements of the problem, though.

Comment: I tried pressing Enter a few dozen times, I never saw it. What do you see in the console when it happens?

Comment: @Barmar if I console.log(pressed.keyCode) then when I hit Enter 13 is logged to the console, indicating that I pressed the Enter key, but the function executes for pressing the c key. I can't manage to replicate it in my example code either, which just makes it more puzzling to me. In the original code I sometimes have to refresh the page to get the bug to start appearing again, and once it starts happening, pressing Enter will always execute the 'c' key function no matter how many times I press Enter until I reload the page.